# preg_match for the email validation I want but somehow I don't know where I messed up

Tags: php, email

oh eh...ya...lots commented there are lots email validation can be used but just that for this one I have to do it like what is mentioned below that's why....

I need to validate email like this

alphanumeric characters followed by @ followed by alphanumeric characters followed by . followed by 2 – 4 more alphanumeric characters

this is what I have done but somehow I know it's the last part after . I messed up but I couldn't find where I messed up....

```
preg_match("/^([0-9]|[a-z])([0-9]|[a-z]|[_-])*@([0-9]|[a-z])*\.([0-9][a-z]){2,4}$/i","")
```

at start I used [0-9]|[a-z])([0-9]|[a-z]|[_-] because I didn't want people able to use _- as the start....so forced start as number/letters only

Comment: You _do_ know that there are collections of validation regexes out there ready to be used?

Comment: nope :P but .... but I need to do make it exactly like what was mentioned for validation though....

Comment: Better use `filter_var()` because you can not take into account all the details of email using `preg_match()`

Comment: If you want to be fully RFC 822 compliant, [you could use this regex](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html), of course...

Answer (score 2):

There must be a million different people that wrote a new regex for email validation. If you are interested in the email format you can just use

```
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

and if the final value is empty the initial one wasn't a valid email address format.

(as an extra step you could try to validate the domain by using this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php)

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with this:

^[0-9a-z_\-]+@[0-9a-z_\-]+\.[0-9a-z]{2,4}$

But as said: there are ready-to-use regexes, much better than trying to reinvent the wheel. Also this current approach does *not* macth all valid addresses and validates some addresses that are illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Which reason of email validation? It is very upset when you try to enter you email and you can't due to the stupid validation. I think it is enoth to check the availability of '@' and '.' signs, in case user unintentionally missed this.

```
$res = preg_match("/@[^@\.]*\./", $str);
```